# Bad request 400: nginx health check /status

Tags: nginx

im doing heath check on my nginx servers i keep getting

different status , it should return 200 only but its keep through 400 bad request as thefollowing

> 10.10.25.2 - - [19/Jun/2014:13:55:06 +0400] "GET /status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "-" "-"
>   10.10.25.3 - - [19/Jun/2014:13:55:07 +0400] "GET /status/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "-" "-"
>   10.10.25.2 - - [19/Jun/2014:13:55:08 +0400] "GET /status/ HTTP/1.0" 400 264 "-" "-" "-"
>   10.10.25.3 - - [19/Jun/2014:13:55:09 +0400] "GET /status/ HTTP/1.0" 400 264 "-" "-" "-"

error log :

```
client sent plain HTTP request to HTTPS port while reading client request headers
```

Here is my Nginx Setup! Am i missing anything here ?

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log info;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include   mime.types;
    default_type text/html;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
        listen       80;
        listen 443;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf/self-ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf/self-ssl.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ssl on` and add `ssl` modifier to `listen 443`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/conf/self-ssl.crt;
    ...
```

Comment: Still the same errors some times return 200 some 400

Comment: How do you do health check?

Comment: through F5 GET /status/  return should be 200 or 301